# Поисковая система в делфи

Tags: delphi

Нужно организовать поисковую систему, представленный код ищет файлы с расширением ТХТ только то, что на диске С, то что в папках оно не ищет, нужно сделать, чтобы поиск по всему диску проводился.

```
 Var SR:TSearchRec; // поисковая переменная
        FindRes:Integer; // переменная для записи результата поиска
    begin
    ListBox1.Clear; // очистка компонента ListBox1 перед занесением в него списка файлов

    // задание условий поиска и начало поиска
    FindRes:=FindFirst('c:\*.txt',faAnyFile,SR);

    While FindRes=0 do // пока мы находим файлы (каталоги), то выполнять цикл
       begin
          ListBox1.Items.Add(SR.Name); // добавление в список название найденного элемента
          FindRes:=FindNext(SR); // продолжение поиска по заданным условиям
       end;
    FindClose(SR); // закрываем поиск
    end;
```

Comment: Рекурсия поможет вам

Comment: google: delphi рекурсивный обход каталогов

Comment: Это - копипаста из delphiworld. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами.

Answer (score 1):

Как писали в комментариях, здесь поможет такая прекрасная штука, как **рекурсия**.

```
var files:TStringList;  // структура, где будет храниться иерархия файлов

...

//данная процедура заполняет "files"(выше) иерархией файлов в УДОБОЧИТАЕМОЙ форме
// "path" - сканируемая папка
// "level" - уровень вложенности

procedure finder(path: string; level:integer=0);
var s:TsearchRec;
i:integer;
level_str:string;
begin
level_str:='';
if level>0  then
for i:=0 to level do level_str:=level_str+'-';
if findfirst(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(Pchar(path))+'*',faanyfile,s)<>0 then exit; 
if(extractfileext(s.Name)='') then  // Если папка, то рекурсивный вызов
finder(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(Pchar(path))+(s.Name),level+1)
else begin
files.Add(level_str+path+s.Name);
end;

application.ProcessMessages;   // обрабатываем сообщения системы

while findnext(s)=0 do
if(extractfileext(s.Name)='') then  // Если папка, то рекурсивный вызов
finder(IncludeTrailingBackSlash(Pchar(path))+(s.Name),level+1)
else begin
files.Add(level_str+path+s.Name);
end;
findclose(s);    
end;
```

---

**где-нибудь в обработчике события выполняем следующий код:**

---

```
begin
files:=Tstringlist.Create;  // структура, где будет храниться иерархия файлов
finder('C:\',0);  // ищем на диске "С"
end.
```

Comment: Еще было бы неплохо код привести в удобочитаемую форму...

Comment: Вас что-то не устраивает? По-моему, код прекрасно читается.

Comment: > По-моему, код прекрасно читается.

Пробелов и отступов очень недостает. Что такое удобочитаемый код можно [узнать](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280) на оф.сайте.